# Keep toggle state on divs using cookie.js after page refresh view jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple code which allows me to toggle betwen two divs which are wraps for two sub navigations (#sub-nav-wrap is the alternative nav). They are fixed to the bottom of the browser :

```
$(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').toggle();
    $('#sub-nav-wrap').toggle();
});
```

});

What I wish to do is to keep the state of each div the same as chosen by the user after page refresh and even if the clicks on a new sub-heading the menu will remain the same, rather then resorting to the default state.

The html is this:

```
<!--- Main Sub Wrap --->
<div id="bottom-wrap">
<!-- Mini Sub Nav -->

<div id="sub-nav-wrapmin" class="snWrap divone">
        <div id="sn-contentmin">
            <div id="sn-likemin"></div> 
            <div id="sn-coffeesml"></div>
            <div id="sn-sharemin"></div>
            <div id="sn-commentsml"></div>
            <div id="toggle-barmin">
                    <div id="sn-sidebrdrmin"></div>
                    <div class="sn-toggle button"></div>
           </div>
              <ul class="sn-comicsmin menu">
                <li><a class="sn-comics" style="background-position: right top" href="#comic.html">Comic</a></li>
                <li><a class="sn-archive" href="#archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                <li><a class="sn-vote" href="#vote.html">Vote</a></li>
                <li><a class="sn-spotlight" href="#spotlight.html">Spotlight</a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
</div>
<!-- Sub Nav -->
<div id="sub-nav-wrap" class="snWrap divtwo">
    <div id="sub-nav-container">
         <div id="sub-nav-content">

                <div id="sn-bnrlft"></div>
                <div id="sn-bnrrgt"></div>
                <div class="sn-dividelft"></div>
                <div class="sn-dividergt"></div>
                <div id="sn-likebg"></div>
                <div id="sn-coffeebtn">
                </div>
                <div id="sn-sharebtn"></div>
                <div id="sn-commentbtn"></div>    
                <div id="toggle-bar">
                    <div id="sn-sidebrdr"></div>
                    <div class="toggle button"></div>
                </div>            
        </div>
        <div id="sub-nav-brdr">
            <ul class="sub-nav-comics menu">
                <li><a class="comics" style="background-position: right top" href="#comic.html">Comic</a></li>
                <li><a class="archive" href="#archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                <li><a class="vote" href="#vote.html">Vote</a></li>
                <li><a class="spotlight" href="#spotlight.html">Spotlight</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is this:

```
#sub-nav-wrap {
    display: none;  
}
```

This is my first time asking, and I have been wracking my brains to get this to work using other similar codes from this site, but nothing is working.
Would appreciate any help...

David

I have constructed a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/replacement4/nKFt7/60) to show how the navigation works without a cookie. 
[This](http://jsfiddle.net/replacement4/nvf3V/3) is my attempt using cookies. I hope it is something simple and I've just miss understood...

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy Thankyou for this example but it doesn't seem to work in the jsFiddle that you linked to. Do you know how to code my example with cookie.js? I would be greatful for a working example of cookie.js with my jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/replacement4/nKFt7/60/

Comment: Hi David, all I did was change the links so they're named - i.e. some text is linked rather than displaying an unlinked URL (before it was just the plain URL). I didn't have time to try to find an answer but I'll have a look now for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need the jQuery cookie [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/) to use cookies that way in jQuery. There is no native support in jQuery for what you are trying to do.

If old browsers are'nt an issue, you could use local storage and do something like:

```
$(function(){
    var wrapmin = localStorage.getItem('wrapmin')||false,
        wrap = localStorage.getItem('wrap')||false;

    if (wrapmin) $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').show();
    if (wrap) $('#sub-nav-wrap').show();

    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').toggle();
        $('#sub-nav-wrap').toggle();
        wrapmin = $('#sub-nav-wrapmin').is(':visible');
        wrap = $('#sub-nav-wrap').is(':visible');
        localStorage.setItem('wrapmin', wrapmin),
        localStorage.setItem('wrap', wrap);
    });    
});
```

You need to change your CSS as well, right now it won't work properly if the elements are initially shown.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nKFt7/61/)

The cookie plugin is well documented.
You set a cookie by giving it a name and a value, ie. two values, not one:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My query was to try to use the cookie.js, I have attempted to use it but I have not succeeded the tutorials do not show me how to use cookie specifically for this. I would be so greatful if yu could show me how to use cookie.js with my example...

Comment: @adeneo: the OP originally asked about cookies specifically - localstorage may not be an option if, like my company, they support IE 6 still. We try to use localstorage where we can but use cookies as a fallback if localstorage isn't available. This is simply done by creating another function which attempts to set localstorage and then proceeds to set the cookie if that fails.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed was that jQuery.cookie was not present in the fiddle, but I assume you have that on the actual site in any case. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nvf3V/9/) you go. I am sure there are more efficient methods but this will still work.

Comment: Thank heavens for smart people! Thank you!